# Find the largest area where a robot can access points on a grid safely

Tags: python

I came across an interesting problem today and i'm kinda stomped on a solution. The question is:

A robot can move around a grid. The robot starts from the origin i.e. (0, 0) and can move up, down, left and right i.e. (x, y+1), (x, y-1), (x-1, y), and (x+1, y) but there are obstacles where it won't be safe to move the robot. To check if a point is safe on the grid, take the absolute sum of the digit x and the absolute sum of the digit y and check if it's less or equal to 23. i.e if the point is (39, 39) => 3+9+3+9 is 24 and the point is not safe or if (-51, 7) => 5+1+7 is 13 then it's safe. The problem statement is find how large the area the robot can access.

Thought process:

The main takeaway after reading this problem is finding the cartesian coordinates whose digits are less than or equal to 23 and based on the coordinates return the area. Now there are a lot of cartesian coordinates that can qualify and make either a rectangle or a square but nevertheless all of them will have the same area. Now i chose to make a square from the origin such that x==y and sum of digits of x and y (which is x) < 23, this might look like

```
i = 0 
   while True:
       units, tens = i%10, (i/10)%10
       x =  units+tens
       y =  units+tens
       if x + y > 23:
           break;
       i+=1
```

But i think i might be wrong as i returns 39 and x, y coordinates returns (12, 12). Then i will have to calculate the area between (x,y), (-x,y), (-x, -y), and (x, -y). I think my approach is wrong and would like anyones thoughts on how to find the largest access area on the grid

Comment: Your solution doesn’t appear to account for the fact that there are safe areas that are unreachable from the origin.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is to start at the origin (assuming it’s safe, otherwise you return 0).  Then try to check if you can move in each direction, adding 1 to your answer for each square you can move to.  A recursive solution seems simplest to code.

Comment: If you’re doing a recursive solution, you probably need to keep track of coordinates you’ve visited so you don’t visit them again.

Comment: @DavidChoweller i thought bfs and not dfs

Comment: @DavidChoweller since it's an infinite board i.e no boundaries of the size of the grid it can run for a while

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Account for negative coordinates, as pointed out by @David Choweller. Also made the solution cleaner by removing some unnecessary indexing.
Edit: Fixed an error in total area calculation, thanks @polapts!

```py
extent = 750
x_s = np.arange(-extent, extent+1, 1)
y_s = np.arange(-extent, extent+1, 1)

### Loop through each point and check if safe
coords = []
for y in y_s:
    x_coords = []
    for x in x_s:
        coords_digits_sum = sum([int(i) for i in str(abs(x))]) + sum([int(i) for i in str(abs(y))])
        if coords_digits_sum <= 23:
            safe = True
        else:
            safe = False
        x_coords.append(safe)
    coords.append(x_coords)


### Initialize the origin as `really_safe` point
coords[extent][extent] = 'really_safe' # Origin

### Iteratively check if a safe point is beside a `really_safe` point
changing = True
while changing == True:
    changing = False
    # Skip the first and last rows and columns because these are just paddings for looking up/down/left/right
    for y,x_coords in enumerate(coords[1:-1], start=1):
        for x,is_safe in enumerate(x_coords[1:-1], start=1):
            if is_safe == 'really_safe':
                continue
            ### look up, down, left, right of the point being checked
            elif is_safe and ('really_safe' in [coords[y-1][x], coords[y+1][x], coords[y][x-1], coords[y][x+1]]):
                coords[y][x] = 'really_safe'
                changing = True

### Count the number of "really safe" points only
really_safe_points = [[1 if safety == 'really_safe' else 0 for safety in x_coords[1:-1]] for x_coords in coords[1:-1]]
plt.imshow(really_safe_points)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

### Exclude first and last rows and columns in total area calculation since those were not iterated over 
plt.title(f"Accessible area: {sum([sum(i) for i in really_safe_points])}. Total area: {((extent-1)*2)**2}")
plt.show()
```

This is the outcome (accessible areas shown in yellow):
[image]

Seems to me like it is not necessary to compute for an infinite board :)

Comment: The coordinates can be negative, according to the OP.  Is that accounted for in this solution?

Comment: Oh yikes I did miss that point! Then again, I imagine that would simply be a mirroring of the plot above about x=0 and y=0. I could try again when I have more time :)

Comment: Indeed it was a mirroring. The updated solution is as shown now

Comment: @Benedictanjw why the 'origin_x, origin_y = 750, 750' if we are told to start from (0, 0)?

Comment: That's an awesome point @polapts. I should have named that variable `extent` (changed now). The origin is still (0,0) in my solution. The line where I reference it is where I initialize it to be a "really safe" point.

Comment: @Benedictanjw, This is a clever solution. One things which is not clear to me is why you iterate through the range 'coords[1:-1]'. You commented it as due to padding but I still don't get. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I didn't explain myself better there. The iteration does not include the first and last columns and rows because those are just there to keep an error from coming up when I try to look around each point. Your comment alerts me to an error I made though in calculating the total area; I should not calculate these first and last columns and rows in the total area (changed now). Thanks for looking through my answer!

Comment: @Benedictanjw: What is the logic behind choosing the value of extent as 750?

Comment: 750 was what I determined after plotting it several times and realizing that that the largest area was already contained within it; any larger an extent is pointless because the robot cannot exceed the boundaries already established with the 750 extent

Answer (score 0):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def sum_of_digit(num):
    sum = 0
    while(num > 0):
        remainder = num % 10
        num = num // 10
        sum = sum + remainder
    return sum

memo = [[0] * 2000 for _ in range(2000)]
dp = [None] * 2000

area = 0
for i in range(-1000, 1000):
    for j in range(-1000, 1000):
        if dp[abs(i)] == None:
           dp[abs(i)] = sum_of_digit(abs(i))
        if dp[abs(j)] == None:
            dp[abs(j)] = sum_of_digit(abs(j))

        if dp[abs(i)] + dp[abs(j)] <= 23:
            memo[i+1000][j+1000] = 1
            area += 1
print(area)
plt.imshow(memo)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

result

```
1253892
```

[image]

How about this? but I think this code is not correct. Because the result is too large.